# Play framework 2.4 internationalization of labels in form helper - Scala

Tags: scala, playframework

I want to translate labels in the form.
I use this code in view:

```
@(adminForm: Form[Admin])(implicit messages: Messages)

@helper.form(action = controllers.admin.routes.Auth.dologin()) {
    @helper.inputText(adminForm("login"), '_label -> "My label" )
    @helper.inputText(adminForm("password"))
}
```

Now I want to replace "My label" with @messages("form.labels.login") to translate it. How it can be done?

Comment: Have you tried `@helper.inputText(adminForm("login"), '_label -> @messages("form.labels.login") )`?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work. Compiler tells there is error.

Comment: Just remove `@`. It's like with `adminForm` You don't have to put `@` before to get 'login' or 'password' value.

Comment: You are right. Please make it an answer